# Type of objects passed from Qml to C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

When passing an object from Qml to C++ am I passing the object itself or a pointer to it? 
Example: I have a C++ slot which i call from within a Qml file and pass an argument to it. What am i passing to the slot, the object or a pointer to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you are passing. `QObject` derived types are intrinsically non-copyable, and as such are passed by pointer.

JS objects may be received as `QVariant` or `QVariantList` for arrays and `QVariantMap` for `Object`s. Those are passed by value and are copies of the passed data. There is also the possibility to use `QJSValue`.

There is a number of object types which are converted to their analogous types, you can see the full list in the [official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html).

Comment: I am passing  a custom object derived from QObject, but which has copy constructor and assignment operator defined. Also, is there a way to explicitly choosing the way it is passed?

Comment: QObject and all subclasses of QObject (direct or indirect) have their copy constructor and assignment operator disabled: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor

Comment: @k.S they are passed by pointer by design. That's how it works.